# DynamicIterable

Tags: java, object-oriented, iterator, lambda

I have written this `DynamicIterable` that can be used as a Lazy Iterable, where you give it a `Supplier<T>` of something and a number of times it can be used. This is an `Iterable` of `T` and it stores the consumed values, so when the iterator is called for a second or additional times, it does not use the `Supplier` again.

Example: when iterating, the supplier makes HTTP requests for the next pages. This `Iterable` allows that and for the next times it does not make new requests and just uses a privately saved list.

I really do not like the `if`statements (because they can often lead to errors, and while developing I had to figure out exactly how they should be) and I wonder if this code could be trimmed down a little more.

- Is this the right approach?
- Can I trim down most comparisons, avoiding errors because of ifs or having to change to much to introduce new functionality?
- Is there any part of the code where I could use one-liners? (Simple one-liners, not those with more than 3 lines for example).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

/**
 * Created by wgoncalves on 24-04-2017.
 * This is a {@link DynamicIterable<T>}, it grows when needed and saves the various items already processed, works almost like
 * a cache.
 *
 * For use all that is needed is a {@link Supplier<Iterable<T>>}, denominated {@link #feeder}, and an indication of how many times
 * is this feeder supposed to be used, {@link #MAX_FEED_COUNT}. This has a very important implication, it is implied that
 * this {@link #feeder} changes state for each time its {@link Supplier#get()} method is called. If this {@link Supplier<Iterable<T>>}
 * is always returning the same thing, the behaviour is not different, this {@link Iterable<T>} will feed of it as many
 * times as it is required (accordingly to {@link #MAX_FEED_COUNT}.
 *
 * After consuming every item ({@link T}) of this {@link Iterable<T>}, for subsequent consumptions the {@link #feeder} will
 * NOT BE USED at all. The elements are kept in a {@link List<T>}, namely {@link #finalList}, so as when the next call
 * to {@link #iterator()} is made, the {@link #finalList#iterator()} is used to return an {@link Iterator<T>}.
 *
 * There is the option to provide a starting set of items to be consumed, before the {@link #feeder} is used for next
 * items. If the method {@link #startWith(Iterable)} is used, the first elements when this {@link Iterable<T>} is consumed,
 * shall be the contents of the {@link Iterable<T>} passed to {@link #startWith(Iterable)} method.
 *
 * A last option is to provide a {@link Runnable} to be used as a way to do work every time {@link #feeder} is used.
 * To include this option there is the method {@link #updating(Runnable)}, where the given {@link Runnable} is invoked
 * after each feed of {@link #feeder}.
 */
public class DynamicIterable<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    /**
     * This is the feeder, for when {@link Iterable<T>} are needed this {@link Supplier<Iterable<T>>} is used
     * to retrieve the next one.
     * If the conditions are valid this supplier will always try to retrieve next elements, even if the same elements
     * are being retrieved over and over again.
     */
    private final Supplier<Iterable<T>> feeder;
    /**
     * Represents the list containing every element ever retrieved, so that when an {@link Iterator<T>} is requested for
     * the second time, this {@link List<T>}'s iterator is returned instead.
     */
    private List<T> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
    /**
     * Indicates how many times {@link #feeder} should be used for retrieving {@link Iterable<T>}.
     */
    private final int MAX_FEED_COUNT;

    /**
     * Controls how many times {@link #feeder} has been used.
     */
    private int feedCount = 0;

    /**
     * Allows the user of this {@link DynamicIterable<T>} to be notified every time the supplied {@link #feeder} is
     * used. This can be useful maybe if the state of something outside should change (most of the cases), as the other
     * option would be apply the change inside {@link #feeder}. This way responsibilities are separated, and this is
     * the recommended usage, but if desired this may not be used at all, and the changing state can be made inside
     * {@link #feeder}.
     */
    private Runnable updater = () -> {  };

    /**
     * Allows controlling of the use of the {@link Iterable<T>} supplied by {@link #startWith(Iterable)} method.
     */
    private boolean toConsumeFirst = false;

    /**
     * Current {@link Iterator<T>} in use, this will change for every {@link #feeder} usage, and for the starting
     * {@link Iterable<T>} if present.
     */
    private Iterator<T> currentIterator;

    /**
     * Supplies the next {@link Iterator<T>}, changing the {@link #feedCount} (incrementing) and also
     * runs the {@link #updater}, for notification of a feed.
     */
    private Supplier<Iterator<T>> nextIterator =  this::getNextIterator;;

    public DynamicIterable(Supplier<Iterable<T>> feeder, int MAX_FEED_COUNT) {
        this.feeder = feeder;
        this.MAX_FEED_COUNT = MAX_FEED_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {

        if(!toConsumeFirst && feedCount >= MAX_FEED_COUNT ) // this means this method has been called previously
            return finalList.iterator();                    //   and so all elements are in finalList

        return new Iterator<T>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                while(currentIterator == null || !currentIterator.hasNext()){
                    if(!toConsumeFirst && feedCount >= MAX_FEED_COUNT ){ // If all feeds are done, this only holds
                        return false;                                    //   if the initial iterable has been consumed
                    }
                    currentIterator = nextIterator.get(); // get next iterator (whatever it may be)
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                if(!hasNext())
                    throw new NoSuchElementException("No Next Element in DynamicIterable");
               return addThenReturnIt(currentIterator.next()); // add to finalList and then return it
            }
        };
    }

    private Iterator<T> getNextIterator() {
        ++feedCount;
        Iterator<T> iterator =  feeder.get().iterator();
        updater.run();
        return iterator;
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for saving an item an then returning the saved item.
     * Instead of creating trash local variables (technically) it still creates it.
     * @param t Item {@link T} to be saved and then returned.
     * @return The same {@link T} received.
     */
    private T addThenReturnIt(T t){
        finalList.add(t);
        return t;
    }


    /**
     * For indication of a previous {@link Iterable<T>} for which to start of.
     * This does not count as a feed, i.e if this set of {@link T}'s is passed and at the same time the
     * feed count ({@link #MAX_FEED_COUNT} is set as 0, these elements are still returned when consuming this current
     * {@link Iterable<T>}, just subsequent feeds are not used.
     * @param startIterable {@link Iterable<T>} representing the starting collection of items to start with.
     * @return Current {@link DynamicIterable<T>} for chaining functionality.
     */
    public DynamicIterable<T> startWith(Iterable<T> startIterable){
        toConsumeFirst = true;

        nextIterator = () -> {
            toConsumeFirst = false;
            nextIterator = this::getNextIterator;
            return startIterable.iterator();
        };

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * For allowing updates whenever a feed operation is made.
     * @param updater {@link Runnable} that is to be run for each feed.
     * @return Current {@link DynamicIterable<T>} for chaining functionality.
     */
    public DynamicIterable<T> updating(Runnable updater){
        this.updater = updater;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Here is a simple usage with `Integer`s (the `Supplier` of `Iterable` of `Integer`s here could be a long running operation that would benefit from laziness).

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    private static List<Integer> list1, list2, list3, list4, list5;
    private static List<Integer>[] contents;


    static {
        list1 = Arrays.asList(10,11,12,13,14,15);
        list2 = Arrays.asList(20, 21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30);
        list3 = Arrays.asList(30,31);
        list4 = Arrays.asList(40,41,42);
        list5 = Arrays.asList(50,51,52,53);

        contents = new List[]{list1, list2, list3, list4, list5};
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{ // You need to handle this exception
        System.out.println("Main App");
        int[] counter = new int[]{1};
        DynamicIterable<Integer> dynamicIterable = new DynamicIterable<>(() -> contents[counter[0]], contents.length - 1)
                .startWith(contents[0])
                .updating(() -> ++counter[0]);

        dynamicIterable.forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}
```